# Не подтягивает ID API через Js

Tags: javascript, laravel, api

Пытаюсь вывести Атрибуты группы категорий, не могу понять почему не хочет подтягивать id группы, выдает api/v2/attributes?groups_id=undefined, но если undefined меняю на 1 все атрибуты видны.
По коду вижу что присваивается группе ID но при нажатии на группу он не передается в группу.

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="col-md-2 group-items" onclick="changeGroups(this)" data-gr="1" data-subcat="false">Основные </span>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-mg-12">
      <fieldset id="group_attributes"></fieldset>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

```js
//Вывод Групп

function renderSubFields(fields) {

  const specifi = document.getElementById('category_groups');
  document.getElementById('category_groups').innerHTML = '';

  if (fields[0].data && fields[1].success) {

    let typeElement = '';
    fields[0].data.forEach(parameter => {
      if (parameter.name === "varchar") typeElement = 'text';
      if (parameter.id === "int") typeElement = 'text';

      let inputFields = `<div class = "row">
      <span  class="col-md-2 group-items" onclick = "changeGroups(this)" data-gr = "${parameter.id}" data-subcat="false">${parameter.name} </span>
      <div class = "row">

        <div class = "col-mg-12">
          <fieldset id='group_attributes'></fieldset>
        </div>

      </div>
      </div>`;
      specifi.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFields);
    })
  }

  }

//Вывод атрибутов групп

function renderSubField(field) {

    const specifications = document.getElementById('group_attributes');
    document.getElementById('group_attributes').innerHTML = '';

    if (field[0].data && field[1].success) {

      let typeElement = '';
      field[0].data.forEach(parameter => {
        if (parameter.type === "text" || parameter.type === "text_select") typeElement = 'input';
        if (parameter.type === "select") typeElement = 'select';
        if (parameter.type === "checkbox") typeElement = 'div';

        const element = document.createElement(typeElement);
        element.id = parameter.id;
        if (parameter.type !== 'checkbox') {
          element.className = 'form-control col mb-3 col-md-3';
        }

        if (parameter.type === 'input' || parameter.type === "text_select") element.type = "text";

        let selElement = document.createElement('span');

        if (parameter.options.length > 0 && parameter.type === 'text_select') {

          selElement = document.createElement('select');
          selElement.className = 'form-control col mb-3 col-md-3';

          parameter.options.forEach(opt => {
            selElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name}</option>`);
          });
        }

        if (parameter.options.length > 0 && parameter.type === 'select') {
          parameter.options.forEach(opt => {
            element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name}</option>`);
          })
        }
        if (parameter.options.length > 0 && parameter.type === 'checkbox') {
          parameter.options.forEach(opt => {
            element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div><span><input id="${opt.id}" type="checkbox" style="opacity:1;"></span><span style="margin-left:40px;">${opt.name}</span></div><br />`);
          })
        }

        let inputField = `<div class = "row"><span  class="col-md-2">${parameter.name}: </span>${element.outerHTML}&nbsp;${selElement.outerHTML}</div>`;
        specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputField);
      })
    }
  }

  var groupsId = '';

  function changeGroups() {
    $(this).click(function () {
      groupsId = $(this).attr('data-gr');

      fetch(`${url}/attributes?groups_id=${groupsId}`)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.json();
          } else console.error(`Status code: ${response.status}`)
        })
        .then(async data => {
          renderSubField(await data)
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Вы что-то непонятное делаете... Зачем в обработчике клика `changeGroups` вы вешаете обработчик клика?

Comment: Не сразу загружать атрибуты группы а при клике на группу. То есть выбирается Категория относительно ее загружаются Группы при клике на группу загружаются Атрибуты.

Comment: Понятно, а зачем в `changeGroups` вешаете обрабочтик клика на `$(this)`?

Comment: Думал на клик сделать, разобрался, как ниже приложу, посмотрел логика кривая, нужно общий API с Групп и Атрибутов переделать вы выводить все вместе, так криво получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комментатор выше был прав вся ошибка была в this, решил таким методом

```js
  var groupsId = '';

  function changeGroups(elem) {
    
      groupsId = $(elem).attr('data-gr');

      fetch(`${url}/attributes?groups_id=${groupsId}`)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.json();
          } else console.error(`Status code: ${response.status}`)
        })
        .then(async data => {
          renderSubField(await data)
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```